# HP fax sending stuck at spooler

Tags: windows-7, fax

On HP Officejet 4500 and Windows 7, when sending a fax, the fax is not sent and the spooler is stuck.
Restarting the spooler doesn't help. Deleting the files from the spooler directory allows to remove them but still doesn't enable fax sending.

Answer (score 1):

End the process `hpofxm08.exe` from the task manager.

Comment: While this might work, could you add some more background to this rather short answer.